# Laravel 5: Request data is null when using an Ajax Post Request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have some problems with receiving data when using an ajax call to EDIT my data. I'm trying to get data that the user has filled in but every time my data is empty or 'null'. Do i need to pass data in ajax call? Or are there other ways in laravel to get the data?

My code at the moment as we speak: 
**showuser.blade.php**

```
    <div class="comments">
    @if(count($user->cars))
        <h1>Auto in reparatie</h1>
        <hr>
        @foreach($user->cars as $car)
        <!-- Form to show each car and edit / delete the cars -->
            <!--<form action="{{ action('CarController@edit', [$user->id, $car->id]) }}" method="POST">-->
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="brand">Merk:</label><br>
                    <select name="brand">
                        @foreach($brands as $brand)
                            <option value="{{$brand->id}}"{{ $brand->id == $car->brand_id ? ' selected="selected"' : '' }}>{{$brand->brandname}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="year">Bouwjaar:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" value="{{$car->year}}" name="year">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="licentsplate">Kenteken:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" value="{{$car->licensplate}}" name="licenseplate">
                </div>
                <div style="float: left; width: 80px">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Edit" id="{{$car->id}}" name="editcar" />
                </div>
            </form>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="deletecar" id="{{$car->id}}">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('[name="editcar"]').click(function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/users/{{$user->id}}/cars/'+this.id,
                success:function(data){
                    if(!data.error){
                      location.reload(true);
                    }
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Routes**

```
 Route::post('/users/{userId}/cars/{carId}', 'CarController@edit');
```

**CarController.php**

```
    // Function to edit a car by ID
public function edit($userId, $carId)
{
    $car = Car::where('id', $carId)->where('user_id', $userId)->first();
    $car->brand_id = request('brand');
    dd(request('year'));
    $car->year = request('year');
    $car->licensplate = ('licenseplate');
    $car->save();
}
```

If I dump and die request('brand'), request('year'), request('licenseplate') i get 'null'.

EDIT:
If I dd $car in my controller, i get the car that i need. Means that there is no problemen finding the right car.

Thx for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't posting any data in the AJAX request. Pass the form values through in an object.

```
var form = $(this).find('form');
var licenseval = form.find('input[name=licenseplate]').val();
var yearval = form.find('input[name=year]').val();
var brandval = form.find('select[name=brand]').find(":selected").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {licenseplate: licenseval, year: yearval, brand: brandval}
    url: '/users/{{$user->id}}/cars/'+this.id,
    success:function(data){
        if(!data.error){
            location.reload(true);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It will load invalid values for data. Because there are multiple `cars` object so multiple input elements with same name will be added to page.

Answer (score 0):

Change following lines:

```
public function edit($userId, $carId)
```

to

```
public function edit(Request $request, $userId, $carId)
```

and use

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

after that you can get `$userId`, `$carId` to use inside the controller function.

Comment: Well, atm I can use $userId and $carId, without using Request $request. I just cant get the data that i need from the showuser.blade

Answer (score 0):

As per your ajax call you are only calling the route

```
Route::post('/users/{userId}/cars/{carId}', 'CarController@edit');
```

but you are not passing any other value. Your application is working as expected.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/users/{{$user->id}}/cars/'+this.id,
        //data: dataObject, ----->Missing Data which you want to pass (brand, year, licenceplate)
        success:function(data){
            //...
        }
    })
```

You are iterating through multiple `$cars` you need to get current `car's` data and pass to ajax call.